# Draw a custom NSTableRowView depending on if next row is group row

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a custom `NSTableRowView` implementation to display my data cells. The table also contains group rows using a simple `NSTextField`.

In my custom row view I need to change the drawing of the bottom separator slightly depending on if the next row below is a data cell (i.e. my custom row) or a group header.

In the case of a group header I don't have to draw the separator, otherwise I'll end up with a 2px separator like shown in the screenshot.

Is there a way to get a reference to the next (or previous) `NSTableRowView` instance from `[NSTableRowView drawBackgroundInRect:...]`?

[image: separators]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Am I correct that your table view delegate implements `-tableView:rowViewForRow:`?

If so, let the table view delegate help:

1. Add a property `drawsSeparator` to your custom row class.
2. In your row class, check the value of this property in `drawRect` and adjust your drawing accordingly.
3. Set `drawsSeparator` on your row in `rowViewForRow`. You can invoke `-tableView:isGroupRow:` with `row + 1` to determine whether the next row is a group (after checking to make sure you're not on the last row).

Comment: It appears the group row always draws a separator above and below my group row, even if I have my own custom NSView row.  Since my custom NSView group row draws a gray 2-pixel separator with appropriate margins above and below, it ends up looking odd.  The effect I'm trying for is similar to the look of a menu, where the ONLY gray line is the separator between groups.

Comment: Hi, probably you should post a new question.