# nstableview custom group row

Tags: cocoa, view, row, nstableview

I'm creating a view-based table view and I'm having some trouble creating a custom group row.  I want to have text in my group row and the default behavior Apple provides is great, but I need to change the color and appearance of the actual row.  I have subclassed `NSTableRowView` and it works, but unfortunately not very well.  Specifically when it starts to float I haven't figured out how to change the alpha of the view without making the text alpha change too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy. Make a new subclass of NSTableRowView and override the method drawRect:. 
It's best to always call  [super drawRect:dirtyRect]; at the beginning.
Then you have the property self.isGroupRow. If it is, then just draw your custom group row.

You can load in the custom Row in the Table View delegate with the method tableView:rowViewForRow:.
Just return an instance of it right there

Comment: Yes basically what I ended up doing except I think drawBackground was the method I used.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this solution should work for you:

[Draw a custom NSTableRowView depending on if next row is group row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324732/draw-a-custom-nstablerowview-depending-on-if-next-row-is-group-row/9405080#9405080)

Comment: If that only gets you part of the way, maybe you could follow up with more specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  In that example he makes a group row by using only an NSTextField which automatically provides the light gray color and floating property (if desired).  In my case I need to change the group row to a darker color and still keep the floating property.  What I did was subclass NSTableRowView to make my custom drawing for the group row, but I was having trouble making it float.  But now that I'm thinking should I just subclass NSTextFieldCell instead?  So basically what do I subclass to do the custom drawing for the group row and what's the correct way to make it float?

Comment: The group row has an isFloating property that can be set.  When the group row floats it goes semi-transparent.  If I just use an NSTextField the transparency is controlled automatically.  But if I subclass using NSTableRowView it's not.  That's what I'm trying to figure out... :-)

Comment: I guess I misunderstood that your question. Sounds like you are able to customize the row views, but they don't appear quite the way you want. I suggest posting screenshots and code, and hopefully someone else can help.